# Activity Transition error, cannot resolve symbol '@transition/explode'

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, activity-transition

I am trying out [Activity Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions) and when I paste below code in my values-21/styles.xml I get error:

> cannot resolve symbol '@transition/explode'

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
  <!-- enable window content transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

  <!-- specify enter and exit transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/explode</item>
  <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/explode</item>

  <!-- specify shared element transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
</style>
```

Comment: agree, their guide is confusing

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Did you create a `res/transition/explode.xml` file with the following contents?

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <explode />
</transitionSet>
```

Comment: You can also use "@android: transition/explode"

Comment: it's `@android:transition/explode` should not use space after `android`

Answer (score 42):

Simplest Answer - Replace it with @android:transition/explode